# SQLite within Android Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently trying to learn Java and therefore I started making an Android application where I need SQLite. Everything seems to work fine, however I can't seem to get the update statement to work.

I've got a .java file with all the SQLite statement that starts with:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TASK1 = "Content";
public static final String KEY_TASK2 = "Name";
public static final String KEY_TASK3 = "Stack";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBName";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Table";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TASK1 + " Varchar UNIQUE, "
        + KEY_TASK2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_TASK3 + " INTEGER"
        + ");";
```

Here's the update I call within my application:

```
public boolean updateRow(Integer task1, Integer task3) {
    String where = KEY_TASK1 + "=" + task1;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TASK3, task3);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

In my main .java file I call:

```
private void ScanOutItem (View view){
    myDb.updateRow("5741000124024", 2);
}
```

which I have bound to a button within my application. 
As I said in the beginning, this is my first application I have made, so I can't promise it's perfect. However if I'm missing something or you can see what's wrong, please do tell. I feel like I've have tried everything, so any help is appreciated.

I have used a guide i saw on youtube, but i made some changes these according to the guide it wasn't fit for my app.

Guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zEKKKEFtHQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, KEY_TASK1+"=?", new String[]{task1});`

or `db.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+KEY_TASK3+"="+task3+" WHERE "+KEY_TASK1+"="+task1);`

if nothing worked from above,try  update `updateRow` Method like this

```
public boolean updateRow(Integer task1, Integer task3) {
    String where = KEY_TASK1 + "=" + task1;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TASK3, task3);
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Insert it into the database. 
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, KEY_TASK1+"=?", new String[]{task1}) != 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Instead of setting `onClick:` in xml, call it from java like this

```
Button myButton  =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //call update method here
    }
});
```

Comment: i think i found one of my issues, i did assign the onClick with a button that redirected to a new file, might be therefore it didn't get applied, however i added a new button which i tried to assign it to now everytime i click it, it comes says "My application has stopped working".. hmm But i did try both of your solution and the same result with both.

Comment: Probably, you are setting the listener in the xml itself, isn't? anwyz, Post the logcat.

Comment: i have removed the onClick function, and added the code you wrote, now my appliication doesn't shut down, however it still doesnt seem like it's updating anything.
i have posted my logs files on:
http://dondyr.dk/verbose.txt
http://dondyr.dk/error.txt
http://dondyr.dk/debug.txt
http://dondyr.dk/info.txt

Comment: It won't update, because you are trying to get data from an invalid url which is understandable from your error log `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://www.googleadservices.com refused`

Comment: I don't have any url within my code? so how can it get a refused connection?  doesn't make much sense to me :s